# Grails and Groovy metaclass package name convention

Tags: grails, groovy, metaclass

I would like to be able to place my metaclasses in the package groovy.runtime.metaclass according to the convention defined here [using the delegating meta class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+Delegating+Meta+Class). I have placed `MyClassMetaClass` in `groovy.runtime.metaclass.mypackage.` for the concrete class `mypackage.MyClass{}`. Unfortunately calls to `MyClass{}` are not intercepted by `MyClassMetaClass{}`. Perhaps this is related to how grails initializes..?

Comment: It looks like you're doing all ok. Post some code so we can have more info. One thing I can think of right now is if you extended the DelegatingMetaClass.

Comment: @TiagoFarias I can get the MetaClass to work when working with a normal groovy project, but not with a grails project.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a delegating meta class in a grails project by changing *BootStrap.groovy*.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def myMetaClass = new MyClassMetaClass(MyClass.class)
        InvokerHelper.metaRegistry.setMetaClass(MyClass.class, myMetaClass)
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Ofcourse this is not the same as implementing delegating meta classes as mentioned in the question.